# PHP - Laravel CloudFlare Session Issues while redirecting

Tags: php, session, laravel, cloudflare

currently I am running my Site with Cloudflare. So if you enter the site, some sessions are generated. But if the site redirects automaticly to another view. All Sessions are gone. I **also** tried it with PHP Native $_SESSION bot this is also not working.

If I am connecting through the Backend IP without Cloudflare , everything is working fine. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are your CloudFlare Page Rules set to [cache static HTML](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172256-How-do-I-cache-static-HTML-)? If so, that may well be the reason your sessions aren't persisting.

If this is still not working you may need to use a [PHP Trusted Proxy library](https://github.com/fideloper/TrustedProxy) to ensure that security policies aren't affecting CloudFlare cookies. Please see the [Laravel Trusted Proxies](https://github.com/fideloper/TrustedProxy) for more info. Once this library is installed, simply set the `proxies` array to match the [CloudFlare IP Address](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips) ranges.

Failing this, I'd recommend reaching out to the CloudFlare support team. This is definitely a unique issue and they will be glad to offer you a helping hand. Just email supportATcloudflareDOTcom from your CloudFlare account email.